# Find retweeterers 2-hop away from a tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Is there a way to get a list with the id's of the retweeterers of a tweet two hop away from the tweet? For example let's say I have a tweet T. User A retweets tweet T. User B retweets user's A retweet.

> [T] -- retweets --> [A] -- retweets --> [B]

I know that I can find A's id with [GET statuses/retweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/:id), but how can I get the B's id?

EDIT:
Let's say I know the id of the tweet I can get A by using this code:

```
IDs ids = twitter.getRetweeterIds(tweet_id);
```

Comment: Can you post some code? For example how you retrieve [T] and its' retweets

Comment: So in order to get the retweets of [T], you need the ID of [T] and nothing else am I correct?

Comment: Hold on I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's getting close to five and I'm very confused over here. I don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but it is a little tricky....

You can use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid to get all the people who have retweeted a specific tweet.  Well, you can get the 100 most recent.

I am @edent.  @LJRich has retweeted me. @winechateau retweets me from @LJRich.

This API call will show both both retweeters in there.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/4493786060150046720
```

However!  If you look through @LJRich's timeline, you'll see that her retweet will have *its own unique status ID!*

```
{
    "created_at": "Mon Jul 28 15:56:11 +0000 2014",
    "id": 493787008138244100,
    "id_str": "493787008138244096",
    "text": "RT @edent: "Accidentally" drunk an entire case of wine?\nUse it to store all the cables you're too stubborn to throw out! http://t.co/rzAW89…",
    ....
    "retweeted_status": {
      "created_at": "Mon Jul 28 15:52:25 +0000 2014",
      "id": 493786060150046700,
      "id_str": "493786060150046720"
```

So, let's now search for who retweeted @LJRich's status...  (remember to use `id_str`)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/493787008138244096.json
```

Hey presto! You can see @winechateau retweeted from @LJRich who retweeted from me.

Comment: I am not sure you are right. What is exactly the id_str value? When I put this `https://twitter.com/edent/status/493786060150046720` it returns me your initial tweet. So it makes sense that I can see @winechateau as a retweeter. But I don't think that's esure me that @winechateau retweeted from @LJRich.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the example.  `id_str` is the ID of the Tweet which is the retweet of mine.  If you call `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/493787008138244096.json` you'll see only people who retweeted her retweet of me.

Comment: Unfortunately, when i call `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/493787008138244096.json` it returns me nothing. Do you get a result?

Comment: I could have sworn blind it was working yesterday... very strange. Sorry!